# Node web app running in Fargate crashes under load with memory and CPU relatively untaxed

Tags: node.js, performance, aws-fargate

We are running a Koa web app in 5 Fargate containers. They are pretty straightforward crud/REST API's with Koa over Mongo Atlas.  We started doing capacity testing, and noticed that the node servers started to slow down significantly with plenty of headroom left on CPU (sitting at 30%), Memory (sitting at or below 20%), and Mongo (still returning in < 10ms).
To further test this, we removed the Mongo operations and just hammered our health-check endpoints. We did see a lot of throughput, but significant degradation occurred at 25% CPU and Node actually crashed at 40% CPU.

Our fargate tasks (containers) are CPU:2048 (2 "virtual CPUs") and Memory 4096 (4 gigs).
We raised our ulimit nofile to 64000 and also set the max-old-space-size to 3.5 GB.  This didn't result in a significant difference.

We also don't see significant latency in our load balancer.

My expectation is that CPU or memory would climb much higher before the system began experiencing issues.
Any ideas where a bottleneck might exist?

Answer (score 4):

The main issue here was that we were running containers with 2 CPUs. Since Node only effectively uses 1 CPU, there was always a certain amount of CPU allocation that was never used. The ancillary overhead never got the container to 100%. So node would be overwhelmed on its 1 cpu while the other was basically idle. This resulted in our autoscaling alarms never getting triggered.
So adjusted to 1 cpu containers with more horizontal scale out (ie more instances).